# How to check for time on a certain day in C#

Tags: c#

I have a program that I need to NOT run for a few hours on Saturday. How can I code it to check to see if the current time is Saturday between 1800 and 2100? I have the date time set and figured I could first check to see if the dayofweek = 6 and then check the time to see if it is between those hours, but I was wondering if someone knew of a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: What sort of "better" are you looking for? (I would compare against DayOfWeek.Saturday explicitly, but other than that...)

Comment: Is this windows service?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: doesn't matter if it's a service or not.  Seeing if the current day is saturday, then testing if the time is between 6pm and 9pm and not executing the method is pretty much the way to do this.

Comment: @ChrisLively: The reason I asked, is to know - how does this code run for 24 hours for it to not run on Saturday? If it is running using a scheduler, it can be configured from outside. There might not be a need to fix the time in the code.

Comment: Who's time are you talking about?   If this program runs on a user's desktop, it's a different problem than if it runs on a server running somewhere on the internet - potentially in a different time zone.

Comment: @shahkalpesh - I agree.  Without knowing how it runs to begin with, it's a bit hard to describe how *not* to run it.  Technically, the approach of comparing the time inside the program means that the program is already running, so you can't really *not* run it at that point.  You could abort, or not execute a particular function, but you can't "not run it" after it's already running.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: I guess I'm looking at it from a different perspective.  If you know the code should never run during that window, then putting a check at the top of the processing method would stop it cold without having to worry if a scheduler was misconfigured..  Of course, this means that reconfiguring it is a recompile...

Comment: @ChrisLively: Sure. A check on the top of the method is a way to prevent it from within the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ((DateTime.Now.Hour >= 18 && DateTime.Now.Hour <= 21) && DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
    //it is between 6 and 9pm on saturday
}
```

or we could invert the entire thing and check for any other time but those times

```
if (!((DateTime.Now.Hour >= 18 && DateTime.Now.Hour <= 21) && DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday))
{
    //it is NOT between 6 and 9pm on saturday
}
```

**Edit:** or if you want to optimise this and ensure no amount of time passes by over the checks, ie. passing into or out of the time period, you could do:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

if ((dt.Hour >= 18 && dt.Hour <= 21) && dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
    //it is between 6 and 9pm on saturday
}
```

or we could invert the entire thing and check for any other time but those times

```
if (!((dt.Hour >= 18 && dt.Hour <= 21) && dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday))
{
    //it is NOT between 6 and 9pm on saturday
}
```

Comment: for a bit more optimisation you could swap the dayofweek condition with the hour one. the day of week condition represent 6/7 chance to fail so this should be checked first (if this is going to be checked many time)

Comment: i was under the assumption that the right to left and parenthesis depth carried into C# from C++, but apparently according to the C# 4.0 language spec, its left to right and depth.

Comment: This looks great! Now, actually, I need to to span from 2300 Saturday night until 0200 on Sunday, so would it be something like this:
'code'
if (!(time.Hour == 23  && time.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)) || (!((time.Hour >= 0 && time.Hour <= 2) && time.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
            {
                //it is NOT between those times
            }
'code'

Answer (score 1):

Use the DateTime library of c#

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(18, 00, 00);
TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(19, 00, 00);
if (date.DayOfWeek.Equals(DayOfWeek.Saturday) && 
                  date.TimeOfDay >= startTime && 
                  date.TimeOfDay <= endTime )
    //Do the operation that you want
```